# How to install NVIDIA VIDEO CODEC SDK?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, sdk

I need it for use with FFmpeg to accelerate encoding.

I've downloaded [nvidia_video_sdk_6.0.1.zip](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-sdk-601) from their [website here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) but there is absolutely no information whatsoever about how to install it on Windows. I've seen one or two posts about linux installation but this is no good to me.

Does anyone know how to install it so FFmpeg will see it? for the moment when I execute command [ffmpeg.exe --enable-nvenc] it gives me an error.

Comment: Those are not codecs for video decoding and encoding, they are the low level programming APIs that programmers could *potentially* use to create a codec or implement support in something like ffmpeg. They are not for general users to unzip and enable support in random programs. SDK stands for Software Development Kit. *You* don't install and use it at all, a programmer who knows how to create a codec and needs to know how to pass data and call graphics card functions in order to process the video uses it.

Comment: I'm confused a little about it, have a look here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro if you go to "NVENC" part they talk about using it to accelerate the process with this SDK I've got.

Comment: They are talking about it being able to be enabled at compile time for ffmpeg. If you are building ffmpeg *from source code* then the sdk would be useful, but if you've downloaded an executable then it is already far too late for the SDK to help you. You need to find a copy of ffmpeg with support already enabled or find out how to build it from sources.

Comment: The command `--enable-nvenc` is an option to pass to the compiler script, not ffmpeg itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will need it.

It is impossible to install NVIDIA Video Codec SDK. Instead, update (download and install) the NVIDIA Windows display driver (look for it at the official site in the section "System Requirements for Video Codec SDK 12.0"):

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk/download